# How do I change login status to logout after user logs in

Tags: php, authentication, sign

I've tried different methods but can't seem to get this work I was going to create a duplicate page to redirect to after logged in but this seems a bit amateur.

Here is my login section:

```
 <?php
session_start();
include("../includes/config.php");
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('location: memberlogin.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```

```
<a href="login/index.php">Login</a>
```

After logged in, I want this to appear instead of login:

```
hello `<?php echo "  "  . $_SESSION['username']; ?> <a href="logout.php">logout</a>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: use an `if`/`else` statement on `$_SESSION['username']`

Answer (score 1):

In the `.php` file that **contains the code that renders the html page**:

```php
$username = $_SESSION['username'] ?? null;
if (true === empty($username)) {
    // show your link to login page
    echo '<a href="login/index.php">Login</a>';
} else {
    // show your link to logout page
    echo '<a href="logout/index.php">Logout</a>'; 
}
```

Comment: <?php $username = $_SESSION['username'] ?? null;
if (true === empty($username)) {
    // show your link to login page
    echo '<a href="login/index.php">Login</a>';
} else {
    // show your link to logout page
    echo '<a href="logout/index.php">Logout</a>'; 
} ?>

Comment: <h3>Join <img src="images/logowhite.png" style="width: 70px; height: auto;"></h3>
       <p style="color:#FFF;">Let's call you by your name be cool</p>
       <?php $username = $_SESSION['username'] ?? null; if (true === empty($username)) { // show your link to login page echo '<a href="login/index.php">Login</a>'; } else { // show your link to logout page echo '<a href="logout/index.php">Logout</a>'; } ?> 
        </div>

Answer (score 1):

Use an [if/else](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) statement on `$_SESSION['username']`

Like:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  echo '<a href="/login">Login</a>';
} else {
  echo '<a href="/logout">Logout</a>';
}
```

Or a short [ternary](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), which does the same

```
<?= !isset($_SESSION['username']) ? '<a href="/login">Login</a>' : '<a href="/logout">Logout</a>' ?>
```

Community wiki, as its way too trivial to earn points.